# Where am I going wrong with this integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

> I am asked to show that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[-\frac{x}{in}e^{-inx}\bigg|^\pi_{-\pi} - \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi-\frac{1}{in}e^{-inx}dx\right] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \left[-\frac{2\pi}{in}e^{in\pi}\right]$$
>   However, I seem to get $0$, so clearly I am doing something wrong?

Here is my attempt

\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[-\frac{x}{in}e^{-inx}\bigg|^\pi_{-\pi} - \int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi-\frac{1}{in}e^{-inx}dx\right] &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{-\pi}{in}e^{-in\pi} + \frac{\pi}{in}e^{in\pi} +\frac{1}{in}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx}dx\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{-\pi}{in}(-1)^n + \frac{\pi}{in}(-1)^n + \frac{1}{in}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx}dx\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{in}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-inx}dx\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{n^2}(e^{-in\pi} - e^{in\pi})\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{2i}{n^2}sin(n\pi)\right] \\
&= 0\end{align}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong. Are you sure the first, original expression (the one on the left) is correct? You have $\;2\pi\;$ on the right side's numerator, and that seems to be wrong (it would be, I think, $\;2i\;$ )...Perhaps some of the limit(s) of the integral is different?

Answer (score 1):

Let's write it better term by term. The first one:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[-\frac{x}{in}e^{-inx}\bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\right]$$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i n}(-\pi e^{-in\pi} - \pi e^{in\pi})$$

$$\frac{-1}{2in}(e^{-in\pi} + e^{in\pi})$$

$$\frac{-1}{in}\cos(n\pi)$$

$$\frac{-1}{in}(-1)^n$$

$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}$$

Which is exactly what you have at the right side of your initial statement, since the integral is zero.

Indeed

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[-\frac{2\pi}{in}e^{inx}\right] = -\frac{1}{in}e^{inx} = -\frac{1}{in}(-1)^n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{in}$$